# Crystal Reports multiple "like" conditions

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-formulas

I have the following statement:

```
    IF {?USER} = "BOB" 
THEN {TABLE.CODE} like "A" or {TABLE.CODE} like "B" or {TABLE.CODE} like "C"
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to shorten all the conditions to the right of the "LIKE" function? It can get very hard to manage for conditions where I have many codes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
IF {?USER} = "BOB" 
THEN {TABLE.CODE} IN ["A", "B", "C"]
```